# is a good idea to use spring repository inside component?

Tags: spring

I was wondering, from the architectural point of view, if there is a good idea to use a Spring `@Repository` inside a Spring `@Component`?

I believe that in a service oriented architecture the `DAO`s must be accessed only through a `@Service`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is valid to call the DAO from the `@Component` class. I always follow this when creating/writing an application.

DAO or Repository layers are the lowest layer and are responsible for all logic related to persisting/retrieving to/from a Data Store. Repositories or DAOs may also consume other repositories but should not consume resources in higher level like Services or Controllers.

Service layer is above Repository layer and encapsulates the business logic of the application. It may consume Repositories and other Services too. Like Repositories, they do not consume higher level resources.

Controller layer is above Service and Repository layers. It may consume Services but never consumes Repositories directly and other controllers. It should only control the user interface using the business layer aka Service.

Comment: This is very clear for me but still it is not answering my question. In the diagram you described, on which layer we can find `@Component`s? Is it ok to inject components into any other layers? Is it ok to inject components into controllers? Is is ok to directly inject DAOs into components?

Comment: What kind of functionality your component class is composed of?

Comment: My class is a simple component that validates an input. In this input I am planning to introduce a repository to validate against the database. The problem was about the layers, in which layer do we put `@Component`s and is it OK to call the `@Repository` from there?

Comment: This sounds more like a helper class. This would be in the service layer as you may call this class from Services or Controllers.